# Add a "Open with Firefox" contextual menu in IE11

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-11, default-browser

Here's my question. We've set IE11 as the default browser for all our Windows PCs (company policy) but we need to use some specific web applications that are only working with Firefox.

Does anyone know a way or a "trick" to add a "Open With Firefox" contextual menu in IE11 or even better to open some specific URLs with Firefox when clicked from Outlook or (probably more difficult) **IE11** ?

Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference in MSDN which adds a new option to the context menu:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It's an old reference but will most likely work in your version of IE. The example shows adding a menu for what was Bing back then ("LiveSearch") and searches for the currently highlighted text.

In your case, you will have to set the key value of HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt registry entry with the physical path of Firefox and change the sample JavaScript code to pass the highlighted text as a parameter to Firefox.

One thing to take note though, this may no longer be supported for future versions of IE - if Microsoft decides not to kill it with Microsoft Edge (formerly Project Spartan) totally.